# Netbean's Java log locations

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans

I'm debugging Java and I haven't been able to find my log location.  I'm actually testing RESTful web services in Netbeans.  If I understand correctly since I'm using Netbeans that's different than the Java server and the logs won't be in the same location.  Any ideas on where I can find these logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is related to your previous question.

If you are on Windows you'll find the GlassFish server logs under Program Files/glassfish-version/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs

If you are on Mac you'll find the GlassFish server logs under /Applications/NetBeans/glassfish-version/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs

The name of the file is server.log